# SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: sharepoint, iis, sharepointfoundation2010

I've installed SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 Home Premium using the tutorial at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx#50

Everything went well except for the last step when I actually try to load either the site or Central Administration.  Instead of a Foundation website, only a blank page appears.

I tried without success the suggested solution to change IIS -> Authentication -> Basic Authentication to Enabled.

After this change it was necessary to enter a username and password when trying to access a Foundation site.  Unfortunately, after entering correct data a "Server Not Found" message appeared and I was not able to proceed.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st step of troubleshooting this is to take SharePoint out of the equation. Setup a new web application in IIS, put in a simple 'hello world' type static html page and try and load that. If you can't then the problem is IIS/networking and not SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, the problem was with IIS.  Strangely enough, SharePoint worked after I went into IIS -> Site -> SharePoint-80 -> Basic Settings -> Connect As (Pass-Through Authentication) -> Specific User and added a user with admin privileges.  I then tried to log into the site using that ID/PW and was denied, however, when I changed Pass-Through Authentication back to "Pass Through User", it worked!  I have absolutely no idea why it worked, but I repeated the process using another SharePoint site and it worked for that as well.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've found a way to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Windows 7 Home Premium and solve the Windows Authentication issue (you CAN actually enable it on Home Premium as well - it's just a manual process, that's all).

You can find the steps I followed on my blog at http://www.rl-soft.com/en/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=21

Hope this helps a few folks!

Raphael.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please put the actual answer in your response instead of just linking to a blog post.